# When is ** understood by file glob()?

Tags: shell, glob

In Java7, `sun.nio.fs.Globs` and `getPathMatcher()` seem to understand the idiom `**` as a way to match zero or more characters **across directory boundaries** (see [the getPathMatcher javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29)).

I could swear some flavor of shell (zsh, bash, tcsh) with some appropriate option settings was giving me the same behavior at some point. But for the life of me I cannot remember how to enable this, and I'm even starting to doubt my memory that I had it working at some point... (Edit: zsh provides that behavior, but only for directories, i.e. `"**.gz"` doesn't match `foo/bar/fubar.gz`, but `"**/*.gz"` does).

In fact, looking at the documentation for various implementations of glob (e.g. POSIX glob(3), glob(7), and Perl's File::Glob) this behavior doesn't seem mentioned anywhere. One exception is Ruby's `Dir.glob()` which explicitly handles `**`.

(original question was: "Does anyone know how to enable this behavior in a unix shell (e.g. zsh)?", but now see the Edited question below).

As a bonus question: does anyone know how to search for `'**'` in Google?...

---

**Edited question**

In fact, it looks like that behavior is indeed accepted by my `zsh` shell (thanks for the responses asserting that fact and prompting me to look further). The reason I thought it wasn't comes from the following subtlety: `"**.gz"` won't match a `<path>/<prefix>.gz`, but `"**/*.gz"` will.  Here is an example. Let's start with the following tree:

```
$ find . -type f | sort
./foo/a.gz
./foo/bar/fubar/abc.gz
./foo/bar/x.gz
./foo/bar/y.gz
./xyz.gz
```

`"**.gz"` doesn't match inside subdirs, just matches what `"*.gz`" would:

```
$ ls -1 **.gz
xyz.gz
```

whereas `"**/*.gz"` does:

```
$ ls -1 **/*.gz
foo/a.gz
foo/bar/fubar/abc.gz
foo/bar/x.gz
foo/bar/y.gz
xyz.gz
```

Now, compare this to the Java behavior:

```
@Test
public void testStar() {
    String pat = Globs.toUnixRegexPattern("*.gz");
    assertEquals("^[^/]*\\.gz$", pat);
}

@Test
public void testStarStar() {
    // '**' allows any number of directories on the path
    // this apparently is not POSIX, although darn useful
    String pat = Globs.toUnixRegexPattern("**.gz");
    assertEquals("^.*\\.gz$", pat);
}
```

Clearly (from the regexps), here the `"**"` matches any character on the path (i.e. it becomes `".*"` in the regexp), whether in a subdirectory or not, and as part of filename or not.

(Disclaimer: `Globs` is a copy of `sun.nio.fs.Globs.toUnixRegexPattern(String glob)` because I needed something that works cross-platform).

Comment: zsh has the `**` recursive globbing feature. As far as I can tell, it's enabled by default. You have to use `setopt extendedglob` to turn on some extra globbing features, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: well, it just doesn't work for me. I must have disabled it somehow and inadvertently. In a dir full of *.png and subdirs with *.png, `echo *.png | wc -w` and `echo **.png | wc -w` just give the same result.  I tried extendedglob but as you mention, it doesn't affect the behavior.

Comment: The zsh version of it doesn't work exactly like that. The `**` matches any number of directories, but to match a file at the end you have to specify it separately. `echo **/*.png`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_03):

> The slash character in a pathname shall be explicitly matched by using
>   one or more slashes in the pattern; it shall neither be matched by the
>   asterisk or question-mark special characters nor by a bracket
>   expression

You could google: "filename expansion pattern".

In bash you could set [`globstar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

> [An asterisk] Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell
>   option is enabled, and `‘*’` is used in a filename expansion context,
>   two adjacent `‘*’`s used as a single pattern will match all files and
>   zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a ‘/’, two
>   adjacent `‘*’`s will match only directories and subdirectories.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ ls **/
$ shopt -u globstar
$ ls **/
```

note: '/' is used here to show only directories.

Answer (score 4):

`**` is interpreted as `(*/)#` (zero or more directories) in Zsh's extended glob syntax, which is implemented in Zsh-specific C code ([`Src/glob.c`](http://zsh.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=zsh/zsh;a=blob;f=Src/glob.c;hb=HEAD)).  This behavior is not optional.

When `shopt -s globstar` is enabled in Bash, it acts similarly in Bash's extended glob syntax, which is implemented in Bash-specific C code ([`pathexp.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/pathexp.c)).  This is off by default.

In traditional UNIX `glob`, `**` is interpreted the same as `*`.